# changing font type of metro ui

Tags: windows-10, fonts, modern-ui

I changed system font to San Francisco (macOS High Sierra) by refering this guide: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-default-system-font-windows-10

So as you can see from the image below blue areas are changed font but metro ui (like taskview of Windows 10, new start menu, metro apps, settings) fonts are still stuck in original.

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGUEO.png)

Here is the settings:

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0iyo.png)

Comment: What is your _question_?

Comment: in the title, changing metro ui font type (like red areas in picture 1 or new settings menu (picture2) etc...)